# Label on UIButton of type UIButtonTypeCustom is not displaying

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, ios6

I want to add a borderless UIButton to my view. Using the interface builder, I do this by dragging a Round Rect Button from the object library. Then, on the attributes inspector, change the Type to Custom and leave the title to "Button." Everything is okay with the interface builder. But, this is not the case with the programmatic approach. Programmatically, this is how I do it:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I run the app, the button is not displayed. Maybe I'm missing something here but when I change the type to `UIButtonTypeRoundRect` the button is displayed. But, again, I want the button to be borderless.

Anyway, I can always use the interface builder. However, I want to understand why the programmatic approach doesn't work. So, does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIButtonTypeCustom` is **really, actually** a custom button type. There are no meaningful values setup for it by default. If you want to display it, you have to set its background color and/or its title color to a non-transparent one:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Set visible values
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someSuperview addSubview:button];
```

Comment: (Oh and yes, this was the first answer, in case you're wondering.)

Comment: @iOS-Deveoper Thanks! (+1 for you too.)

Comment: @iOS-Deveoper I'm alive here, quite regularily :)

Comment: I see the problem now... Somewhere in the code, the color was being set like this: button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; When I changed it to [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; it run as expected. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here i have used your code the Thing you missing is that

```
 [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was in the same situation.
I do not know why somewhere in my code there was

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Once I've deleted that line I was able to set my button frame without any issues.
Hope this helps